# Code in Eclipse doesn't work in IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, bukkit

So I'm switching from Eclipse to IntelliJ after 2 days I saw a weird problem. When I copy the exact same code from Eclipse to IntelliJ, the code won't work in IntelliJ.

Code:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    public void onEnable() {

    }

    public int number = 10;


    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage("Console Only");
            return true;
        }

        Player player = (Player) sender;



        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bomb")) {
            if(args.length == 0){
                player.sendMessage("You must specify a player");
                return true;
            }

            Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

            if(target == null){
                player.sendMessage("Couldn't find that player!");
                return true;
            }

                Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (number != -1) {
                            if (number != 0) {
                                target.sendMessage("§a§l" + number + "§7 until you will explode!");
                                number--;
                            } else {
                                number--;
                                Location loc = target.getLocation();
                                World world = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("world");
                                world.createExplosion(loc, 2F);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, 0, 20L);
            }
            return true;
    }
}
```

This code works in Eclipse but not in IntelliJ.
IntelliJ says that I need to add a 'final' to this part of the code:

```
Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
```

But when I do that the plugin just doesn't work anymore.
Why does it work in Eclipse but not in IntelliJ?

Comment: You're compiling with Java 8 in Eclipse, but with a previous version in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is probably not a compile error, but an IntelliJ code inspection. These give warnings, like a red underline (like compile error), a yellow underline (like compiler warning), etc. If you place your caret somewhere that's marked red, and press alt+enter, you should be given some choices, amongst them something like "edit inspection settings". Here you can disable this inspection. Or, you could just start using `final`..